# PUT request for file in django-react-redux

Tags: django, reactjs, file, redux, django-rest-framework

I tried to apply put request in Django-react-redux for the file. What I was trying to do is, the user should have to replace the file using ID filed from put request. I write the following code in `django-restframework`.

```py
class EarSingleView(APIView):

    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def get(self, request, ear_id, *args, **kwargs):
        ear = Ear.objects.get(pk=ear_id)
        serializer = EarSerializers(ear)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def delete(self, request, ear_id, *args, **kwargs):
        ear = Ear.objects.get(pk=ear_id)
        ear.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    def put(self, request, ear_id):
        ear = Ear.objects.get(pk=ear_id)
        serializer = EarSerializers(ear, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My get request and delete request working perfectly. But in `PUT` request, If I tried to change the file filed and try to submit, the following error will occur, `400:Bad request. detail: "Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None"`

My form looks like this,

```html
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
  <Input
    placeholder="Enter layer name..."
    name="name"
    value={name}
    onChange={this.onChange}
   />

   <input
     type="file"
     name="fileName"
     onChange={this.handleFileChange}
   />
</form>
```

My form onSubmit event is looks like this,

```js
onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {
      name,
      file,
    } = this.state;

    const newEARData = {
      id: this.props.idNumber,
      name,
      file,
    };

    axios
    .put(`http://localhost:8000/api/ear/${newEARData.id}`, newEARData, {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_EAR,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
}
```

get request is looks like this,

```js
 axios
    .get(`http://localhost:8000/api/ear/${id}`)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({ type: GET_DETAILED_EAR, payload: res.data });
    })
```

Please anyone suggest to me what is the best way to replace the file (put request) in the django-react-redux setup?

Comment: Can you add the JavaScript code of gey API request ?

Comment: I updated the question, please help me. I am very close to the solution as answered by @vivek. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For passing multipart formdata, you need to pass it via `FormData`, simple json object won't work

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id',this.props.idNumber)
formData.append('name',name)
formData.append('file',file)
axios.put(`http://localhost:8000/api/ear/${this.props.idNumber}`, formData, {
    headers: {
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
})
```

Comment: I just tried this method. It occurs 404 undefined error. I think `this.props.idNumber` is not appending.

Comment: @dhiraj, updated answer, url was wrong , it should be `http://localhost:8000/api/ear/${this.props.idNumber}`, check now

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is working, but still have a one problem, If I only want to update the `name` filed only, it shows the error message of `400 bad request, file: ["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."]` how can I solve this issue?

Comment: in that case just pass `formData.append('id',this.props.idNumber)
formData.append('name',name)` don't append the form

Comment: Don't append the `file` field you mean?

Comment: Actually I don't want to neglect the file filed. But what if the user want to change the file? it won't update, right?(because we didn't append the file field). I want to submit the form whether user can only edit the `name` field or only edit the `file` field or he can edit both fields without any error. how can I do that? please help me

Comment: I think I need to write the condition to append the file filed. The file filed only need to be append when it changes the state. But how can I write such a condition can you help me please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215754/discussion-between-vivek-doshi-and-dhiraj).